# Is there a way in Python to return a value via an output parameter?

Tags: python

Some languages have the feature to return values using parameters also like C#.
Let’s take a look at an example:

```
class OutClass
{
    static void OutMethod(out int age)
    {
        age = 26;
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        int value;
        OutMethod(out value);
        // value is now 26
    }
}
```

So is there anything similar in Python to get a value using parameter, too?

Comment: Hard question to understand. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @tokland: I think what the OP wants to do is to pass arguments by reference instead of by value as Python normally does.

Comment: Did you mean "output" - "return"? Or something like pass parameters by reference?

Comment: Check out this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Python can return a tuple of multiple items:

```
def func():
    return 1,2,3

a,b,c = func()
```

But you can also pass a mutable parameter, and return values via mutation of the object as well:

```
def func(a):
    a.append(1)
    a.append(2)
    a.append(3)

L=[]
func(L)
print(L)   # [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Yes, this is the way to go about multiple return values in python. Returning tuples is better than trying to modify one of the given parameters

Comment: I am not quite sure if saying "returning multiple values" is appropriate here. It actually returns one value which is a `tuple` that contains multiple elements.

Comment: There is reason. For example well known 'TryDo' pattern:
`if try_parse(out result): print(result)`. This code is clean. Try to use tuples here and it will become ugly.

Comment: That's not valid Python.  In Python it would be `result = parse(something)` that throws exception on error and wrapped in `try/except`.

Comment: "There is no reason" sometimes means "I haven't thought of a reason". @renadeen that's a great point, I actually came here looking for a TryDo pattern. If-else trees would be a better way to code multiple parsing tries. Mark Tolonen, try/except would nest deeper with each try, or I haven't thought of a way that wouldn't.

Comment: @Bob Put all the parses in one try, or return None and use `if result: print(result)` or the like to process individually, or return a parse class instance that holds the results and/or errors.

Comment: @Mark we probably need less hypothetical and more code. Would love to discuss over a whiteboard on a spare afternoon. (Whatever that is, I'm free in 2050.) I suspect putting the parses in one try just complicates the try-clause, and doesn't apply if each parse requires different handling. I think you're right, a parse class is the classier way, and the way I went, though I think that code is a little more cluttered than a **multiple-output function** would be.

Comment: Not working if not use .append() ```def f(a):
    a=[122]
    
x=[333]
f(x)
x
[333]```

Comment: @Nam That’s because that isn’t mutation of the original object. You’re assigning a new object. `a` has to remain a reference to the original list, and the contents modified. It doesn’t have to be append...any method the modifies the original list will do. Just don’t use assignment.

Comment: Multiple assignments do not replace output parameters in cases where the function returns a success flag and puts the result in an output parameter. Such a function may be put inside an `if` statement, whereas in *Python* you have first to assign and then to test. Bidirectional input/output parameters are also indispensable as accumulators in functions that append strings or increment numerical values. How can one implement a normal function, rather than an object method, that appends one string to another?

Comment: @Ant_222 Strings are immutable, so you must reassign: `s = ''.join(s,other)`

Comment: Sorry for joining the discussion so late, but this helps me because I need an optional (additional) return parameter for my function and I don't see/know another way, especially without breaking the existing legacy code.

Answer (score 8):

You mean like passing by reference?

For Python object the default is to pass by reference. However, I don't think you can change the reference in Python (otherwise it won't affect the original object).

For example:

```
def addToList(theList):   # yes, the caller's list can be appended
    theList.append(3)
    theList.append(4)

def addToNewList(theList):   # no, the caller's list cannot be reassigned
    theList = list()
    theList.append(5)
    theList.append(6)

myList = list()
myList.append(1)
myList.append(2)
addToList(myList)
print(myList)   # [1, 2, 3, 4]
addToNewList(myList)
print(myList)   # [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Python is **not** call by reference.

Answer (score 4):

Pass a list or something like that and put the return value in there.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, if you feel like reading some code, I think that `pywin32` has a way to handle output parameters.

In the Windows API it's common practice to rely heavily on output parameters, so I figure they must have dealt with it in some way.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with mutable objects, but in most cases it does not make sense because you can return multiple values (or a dictionary if you want to change a function's return value without breaking existing calls to it).

I can only think of one case where you might need it - that is threading, or more exactly, passing a value between threads.

```
def outer():
    class ReturnValue:
        val = None
    ret = ReturnValue()
    def t():
        # ret = 5 won't work obviously because that will set
        # the local name "ret" in the "t" function. But you
        # can change the attributes of "ret":
        ret.val = 5

    threading.Thread(target = t).start()

    # Later, you can get the return value out of "ret.val" in the outer function
```

Comment: `Queue` or `Manager` works better for this purpose with multithreading or multiprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [Tark-Tolonen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/235698/mark-tolonen)'s answer:

Please absolutely avoid altering the object reference of the output argument in your function, otherwise the output argument won't work. For instance, I wish to pass an ndarray into a function `my_fun` and modify it

```py
def my_fun(out_arr)
    out_arr = np.ones_like(out_arr)
    print(out_arr) # prints 1, 1, 1, ......
    print(id(out_arr))

a = np.zeros(100)
my_fun(a)
print(a) # prints 0, 0, 0, ....
print(id(a))
```

After calling `my_fun`, array `a` stills remains all zeros since the function `np.ones_like` returns a reference to another array full of ones and assigns it to `out_arr` instead of modifying the object reference passed by `out_arr` directly. Running this code you will find that two `print(id())` gives different memory locations.

Also, beware of the array operators from numpy, they usually returns a reference to another array if you write something like this

```py
def my_fun(arr_a, arr_b, out_arr)
    out_arr = arr_a - arr_b
```

Using the `-` and `=` operator might cause similar problems. To prevent having `out_arr`'s memory location altered, you can use the numpy functions that does the exactly same operations but has a `out` parameter built in. The proceeding code should be rewritten as

```py
def my_fun(arr_a, arr_b, out_arr):
    np.subtract(arr_a, arr_b, out = out_arr)
```

And the memory location of `out_arr` remains the same before and after calling `my_fun` while its values gets modified successfully.