# AutoCAD Handle and HandelToObject contradiction in python and VBA macro

Tags: python, excel, vba, autocad, comtypes

I'm trying to get XRecords' data [DXF group codes + values] in a python script with the help of the VBA macro and the python function provided in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45773515/8070933).

In python, I get the handle of the XRecord using the `Handle` property, however, not all XRecords does return successfully their data, and an **Unknown handle** error is thrown at the line `Set myXRecord = mydoc.HandleToObject(handler)` at the VBA macro.

I've looked for an explanation, one of them is [this one](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/autodesk.autocad.customization.vba/HoVKkndgMYU), but my case is different in that it *takes the XRecord's handle at first* then supply it, so, no assumptions are made on how handles are created at the AutoCAD drawing.

So, **how can an XRecord return its handle, then `HandleToObject` method can't find that XRecord from its `Handle` property's value?!**

**Edit:-**

I guess the problem is with `HandleToObject` itself, I get python to preview the handle which invokes the error (say "3E7") then I open the drawing and get the XRecord's data from the ordinary  `entget` preview using `(entget (handent "3E7"))` in AutoCAD's command line, and the result is successful.

```
((-1 . <Entity name: 7ff649f06e70>) (0 . "XRECORD") (5 . "3E7") (102 . "{ACAD_REACTORS") (330 . <Entity name: 7ff649f06e20>) (102 . "}") (330 . <Entity name: 7ff649f06e20>) (100 . "AcDbXrecord") (280 . 1) (1 . "Wall1"))
```

Can there be any workaround to this issue?!!

Answer (score 0):

## NOTE: THIS IS NOT A SOLUTION, IT'S ANOTHER WAY TO REFERENCE XRECORDS

I've replaced dealing with object's *handle* to object's *object ID*, then I've taken a copy of the vba macro, renamed the copied macro to *"getfromid"*, taken a copy of `XRecord_return`, renamed the copy to `XRecord_return_1`, then made minor changes as following:-

**At the vba macro `getfromid`**

1- Go to line `Set myXRecord = mydoc.HandleToObject(handler)` and replace `HandleToObject` with `ObjectIDToObject`

2- Change `Dim name2 As String` to `Dim name2 As String, handler As LongPtr`

**At the python function `XRecord_return_1`**

1- Change the line `xl.Application.Run("facilitator.xlsm!mod_facilitate.getxrecord")` to `xl.Application.Run("facilitator.xlsm!mod_facilitate.getfromid")`

---

This should avoid the source of **Unknown handle** error.