# python pygame update the score when shoot the aliens

Tags: python, pygame

I am doing the function of shooting the alien then update the score on screen.

my thought is

1. setting `self.score = 0` in the `class Game_state` for initinal
2. setting `self.alien_score =50` in the `class Setting` for add score
3. setting `self.score = pygame.font.Font(None,80).render(str(state.score),True,self.color)` in `class Scoreboard` for blit the score on the screen
4. check `collisions=pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bullets,aliens,False,True)` in `class Function`

```py
if collisions :
    state.score += setting.alien_score
    sb=Scoreboard(setting,state)`
```

when the bullet shot alien then add the score and update score on the screen.

the `class Scoreboard`  as blew:

```py
class Scoreboard():
    def __init__(self,setting,state):
        self.color = (0,0,0)
        self.score = pygame.font.Font(None,80).render(str(state.score),True,self.color)
        self.rect = self.score.get_rect()
        self.rect.top = setting.screen_rect.top
        self.rect.right = setting.screen_rect.right-30
    def blit_score(self,setting):
        setting.screen.blit(self.score,self.rect)
```

Now i do it but when the bullets shoot the aliens thers's no score update on the screen, the value is always 0, i dont know what's cause it?
Is that the wrong way to instace the class use `sb=Scoreboard(setting,state)`?

How to update the score if i write it in `__init__`

when i modify the `class Scoreboard` as :

```
class Scoreboard():
    def __init__(self,setting,state):
        self.color = (0,0,0)
        self.prep_score(setting,state)
    def prep_score(self,setting,state):
        self.score = pygame.font.Font(None,80).render(str(state.score),True,self.color)
        self.rect = self.score.get_rect()
        self.rect.top = setting.screen_rect.top
        self.rect.right = setting.screen_rect.right-30
    def blit_score(self,setting):
        setting.screen.blit(self.score,self.rect)
```

then change check `collisions=pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bullets,aliens,False,True)` in `class Function`

```
if collisions :
    state.score += setting.alien_score
    sb.prep_score(setting,state)
```

the score shows correct, in which way i can update the score when the whole parameters in `__init__` as the first wrong example i showed?

here's the codes:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys,os
import pygame
from time import sleep


class Setting():
    def __init__(self,width,height):
        self.w=width
        self.h=height
        self.flag=pygame.RESIZABLE
        self.color=(255,255,255)
        self.speed=1.5
        self.ship=3
        self.screen=pygame.display.set_mode((self.w,self.h),self.flag)
        self.screen_rect=self.screen.get_rect()
        pygame.display.set_caption("Muhaha")
        self.dynamic_setting()
    def dynamic_setting(self):
        self.alien_score = 50
class Game_state():
    def __init__(self,setting):
        self.reset(setting)

    def reset(self,setting):
        self.ship_left = setting.ship
        self.score = 0

class Scoreboard():
    def __init__(self,setting,state):
        self.color = (0,0,0)
        self.score = pygame.font.Font(None,80).render(str(state.score),True,self.color)
        self.rect = self.score.get_rect()
        self.rect.top = setting.screen_rect.top
        self.rect.right = setting.screen_rect.right-30
    def blit_score(self,setting):
        setting.screen.blit(self.score,self.rect)

class Ship():
    def __init__(self,screen,setting):
        temp=pygame.image.load("/home/finals/python/alien/image/title.jpg").convert_alpha()
        self.ship=pygame.transform.smoothscale(temp,(200,200))
        self.rect=self.ship.get_rect()


        '''setting the ship position''' 
        self.rect.center=setting.screen_rect.center
        self.rect.bottom=setting.screen_rect.bottom
        '''setting the temp x,y to store value'''
        self.x=float(self.rect.centerx)
        self.y=float(self.rect.centery)



class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,setting,ship):
        super().__init__()
        self.rect=pygame.Rect(0,0,3,10)
        self.rect.centerx=ship.rect.centerx
        self.rect.top=ship.rect.top
        self.color=(0,0,0)
        self.speed=2
        '''setting the temp y to store speed'''
        self.y=float(self.rect.centery)
    def move_bullet(self):
        self.y -= self.speed
        self.rect.y= self.y
    def draw_bullet(self,setting):
        pygame.draw.rect(setting.screen,self.color,self.rect)

class Alien(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        pic=pygame.image.load("/home/finals/python/alien/image/ship.jpg").convert_alpha()
        self.image=pygame.transform.smoothscale(pic,(100,100))
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        self.rect.x=(self.rect.width)
        self.speed=1
        self.direction = 1

    def create(self,setting,aliens):
        '''calculate how many aliens can be placed on screen''' 
        spacex=setting.w-(self.rect.x)*2
        spacey=(setting.h)/2-self.rect.y
        alien_number=int(spacex/(2*(self.rect.width)))
        alien_row=int(spacey/(2*(self.rect.height)))
        for row in range(alien_row):
           for number in range(alien_number):
               alien=Alien()
               '''setting position for every alien'''
               alien.x=alien.rect.x+2*alien.rect.width*number
               alien.rect.x=alien.x

               alien.rect.y=alien.rect.y+2*alien.rect.height*row
               aliens.add(alien)

    def update(self):
      '''update alien position '''
      self.x += (self.speed*self.direction)
      self.rect.x =self.x


class Function():
    def __init__(self):
       '''setting lable for ship move'''
       self.moving_up   = False
       self.moving_down = False
       self.moving_left = False
       self.moving_right = False
    def event(self,bullets,setting,ship):      
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key ==pygame.K_z:
                    if len(bullets) < 10:
                       bullets.add(Bullet(setting,ship))
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    self.moving_up=True
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    self.moving_down=True
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    self.moving_left=True
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.moving_right=True
                elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                       sys.exit()

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    self.moving_up=False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    self.moving_down=False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    self.moving_left=False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.moving_right=False

    def move(self,setting,ship):
        '''set the ship not move out of the screen'''
        if self.moving_up == True and ship.rect.top >= 0:
           ship.y -= setting.speed
        if self.moving_down == True and ship.rect.bottom <= setting.h:
            ship.y += setting.speed
        if self.moving_left == True and ship.rect.left >= 0:
            ship.x -= setting.speed
        if self.moving_right == True and ship.rect.right <= setting.w:
            ship.x += setting.speed
        '''update ship position'''
        ship.rect.centerx=ship.x
        ship.rect.centery=ship.y

    def check_bullet_collide(setting,alien,state,sb,bullets,aliens):
        '''check bullets and aliens collide'''
        collisions=pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bullets,aliens,False,True)
        '''add the score and update it'''
        if collisions :
            state.score += setting.alien_score
            sb=Scoreboard(setting,state)
        '''reset the bullets and aliens '''
        if len(aliens) ==0:
            bullets.empty()
            alien.create(setting,aliens)

    def blit_bullet(setting,alien,state,sb,bullets,aliens):
        '''create bullet'''           
        for bullet in bullets.sprites():
             pygame.draw.rect(setting.screen,bullet.color,bullet.rect)
             bullet.y -= bullet.speed
             bullet.rect.y=bullet.y
        '''check the bullets whether in screen'''
        for bullet in bullets:
            if bullet.rect.y <= 0:
                bullets.remove(bullet)
        Function.check_bullet_collide(setting,alien,state,sb,bullets,aliens)

    def check_alien_edge(setting,aliens):
        '''check the alien touch the edge of screen'''
        for alien in aliens.sprites():
            if alien.x > setting.w or alien.x < 0:
               Function.change_alien_direction(aliens)
               break

    def change_alien_direction(aliens):
        '''if touch the screen move down and change the direction'''
        for alien in aliens.sprites():
            alien.rect.y +=50
            alien.direction *= -1

    def update_alien(setting,alien,aliens):
        Function.check_alien_edge(setting,aliens)
        aliens.update()

    def blit_alien(setting,alien,aliens):
        aliens.draw(setting.screen)



    def ckeck_ship_collide(setting,ship,alien,state,aliens):
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(ship,aliens):
           state.ship_left -= 1
           if state.ship_left >= 0:
               aliens.empty()
               alien.create(setting,aliens)
               state.ship_left -= 1

               ship.rect.center = ship.screen_rect.center
               ship.rect.bottom = ship.screen_rect.bottom

               ship.x = float(ship.rect.centerx)
               ship.y = float(ship.rect.centery)

               sleep(0.5)
           else:
               print("Gamer over")

    def blit_screen(self,setting,ship,alien,sb,bullets,aliens):
        setting.screen.fill((255,255,255))
        setting.screen.blit(ship.ship,ship.rect)
        setting.screen.blit(sb.score,sb.rect)
        self.event(bullets,setting,ship)
        Function.blit_alien(setting,alien,aliens)


def game():
    pygame.init()
    setting=Setting(1200,800)
    screen=setting.screen 
    state=Game_state(setting)
    sb=Scoreboard(setting,state)
    ship=Ship(screen,setting)
    function=Function()
    bullet=Bullet(setting,ship)
    bullets=pygame.sprite.Group()
    alien=Alien()
    aliens=pygame.sprite.Group()
    alien.create(setting,aliens)                  

    while True:
        function.blit_screen(setting,ship,alien,sb,bullets,aliens)
        function.move(setting,ship)
        Function.update_alien(setting,alien,aliens)
        Function.blit_bullet(setting,alien,state,sb,bullets,aliens)
        Function.ckeck_ship_collide(setting,ship,alien,state,aliens)
        pygame.display.flip()
game()
```

[image: ship.jpg]
[image: title.jpg]

Comment: Can you share images for your game? I want to debug it on my PC.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Arguments are just inputs and not outputs, so you can't do it like that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way in Python to return a value via an output parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702249/is-there-a-way-in-python-to-return-a-value-via-an-output-parameter)

Comment: @Alderven  hi, I have added the images

Comment: @Rabbid76 i want to find another way if i do not use ```def pre_score()``` in ``class Scoreboard``` then to update the score on screen

Comment: @M_Sea Why? A method is the common way to change an object. Anyway the way xou try to do it won't work at all

Comment: @Rabbid76 i got it,so use the `def prep_score` is the best way to change the `state.score` and whole parameters write in `__init__` can't be changed when the `state.score` changed, right??

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean. If you do `sb=Scoreboard(setting,state)`, then you create a new instance of  `Scoreboard`. But the original instance (`sb` in the function `game`) is not changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206186/discussion-between-m-sea-and-rabbid76).

Answer (score 0):

I mainly changed your class "Function()" by adding `self.setting = setting` so you don't need to pass `setting` as argument for every single function of this class.

I advise you to do the same for other classes. For example you use the argument `alien` very often in your Function class, so you could add it as `self.alien = alien`.

```
import sys,os
import pygame
from time import sleep


class Setting():
    def __init__(self,width,height):
        self.w=width
        self.h=height
        self.flag=pygame.RESIZABLE
        self.color=(255,255,255)
        self.speed=1.5
        self.ship=3
        self.screen=pygame.display.set_mode((self.w,self.h),self.flag)
        self.screen_rect=self.screen.get_rect()
        pygame.display.set_caption("Muhaha")
        self.dynamic_setting()
    def dynamic_setting(self):
        self.alien_score = 50
class Game_state():
    def __init__(self,setting):
        self.reset(setting)

    def reset(self,setting):
        self.ship_left = setting.ship
        self.score = 0

class Scoreboard():
    def __init__(self,setting,state):
        self.color = (0,0,0)
        self.score = pygame.font.Font(None,80).render(str(state.score),True,self.color)
        self.rect = self.score.get_rect()
        self.rect.top = setting.screen_rect.top
        self.rect.right = setting.screen_rect.right-30
    def blit_score(self,setting):
        setting.screen.blit(self.score,self.rect)

class Ship():
    def __init__(self,screen,setting):
        temp=pygame.image.load("/home/finals/python/alien/image/title.jpg").convert_alpha()
        self.ship=pygame.transform.smoothscale(temp,(200,200))
        self.rect=self.ship.get_rect()


        '''setting the ship position''' 
        self.rect.center=setting.screen_rect.center
        self.rect.bottom=setting.screen_rect.bottom
        '''setting the temp x,y to store value'''
        self.x=float(self.rect.centerx)
        self.y=float(self.rect.centery)



class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,setting,ship):
        super().__init__()
        self.rect=pygame.Rect(0,0,3,10)
        self.rect.centerx=ship.rect.centerx
        self.rect.top=ship.rect.top
        self.color=(0,0,0)
        self.speed=2
        '''setting the temp y to store speed'''
        self.y=float(self.rect.centery)
    def move_bullet(self):
        self.y -= self.speed
        self.rect.y= self.y
    def draw_bullet(self,setting):
        pygame.draw.rect(setting.screen,self.color,self.rect)

class Alien(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        pic=pygame.image.load("/home/finals/python/alien/image/ship.jpg").convert_alpha()
        self.image=pygame.transform.smoothscale(pic,(100,100))
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        self.rect.x=(self.rect.width)
        self.speed=1
        self.direction = 1

    def create(self,setting,aliens):
        '''calculate how many aliens can be placed on screen''' 
        spacex=setting.w-(self.rect.x)*2
        spacey=(setting.h)/2-self.rect.y
        alien_number=int(spacex/(2*(self.rect.width)))
        alien_row=int(spacey/(2*(self.rect.height)))
        for row in range(alien_row):
        for number in range(alien_number):
            alien=Alien()
            '''setting position for every alien'''
            alien.x=alien.rect.x+2*alien.rect.width*number
            alien.rect.x=alien.x

            alien.rect.y=alien.rect.y+2*alien.rect.height*row
            aliens.add(alien)

    def update(self):
    '''update alien position '''
    self.x += (self.speed*self.direction)
    self.rect.x =self.x


class Function():
    def __init__(self,setting):
    '''setting lable for ship move'''
    self.moving_up   = False
    self.moving_down = False
    self.moving_left = False
    self.moving_right = False
    self.setting = setting

    def event(self,bullets,ship):      
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key ==pygame.K_z:
                    if len(bullets) < 10:
                    bullets.add(Bullet(setting,ship))
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    self.moving_up=True
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    self.moving_down=True
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    self.moving_left=True
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.moving_right=True
                elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    sys.exit()

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    self.moving_up=False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    self.moving_down=False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    self.moving_left=False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.moving_right=False

    def move(self,ship):
        '''set the ship not move out of the screen'''
        if self.moving_up == True and ship.rect.top >= 0:
        ship.y -= self.setting.speed
        if self.moving_down == True and ship.rect.bottom <= self.setting.h:
            ship.y += self.setting.speed
        if self.moving_left == True and ship.rect.left >= 0:
            ship.x -= self.setting.speed
        if self.moving_right == True and ship.rect.right <= self.setting.w:
            ship.x += self.setting.speed
        '''update ship position'''
        ship.rect.centerx=ship.x
        ship.rect.centery=ship.y

    def check_bullet_collide(self,alien,state,sb,bullets,aliens):
        '''check bullets and aliens collide'''
        collisions=pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bullets,aliens,False,True)
        '''add the score and update it'''
        if collisions :
            state.score += self.setting.alien_score
            sb=Scoreboard(self.setting,state)
        '''reset the bullets and aliens '''
        if len(aliens) ==0:
            bullets.empty()
            alien.create(self.setting,aliens)

    def blit_bullet(self,alien,state,sb,bullets,aliens):
        '''create bullet'''           
        for bullet in bullets.sprites():
            pygame.draw.rect(self.setting.screen,bullet.color,bullet.rect)
            bullet.y -= bullet.speed
            bullet.rect.y=bullet.y
        '''check the bullets whether in screen'''
        for bullet in bullets:
            if bullet.rect.y <= 0:
                bullets.remove(bullet)
        self.check_bullet_collide(alien,state,sb,bullets,aliens)

    def check_alien_edge(self,aliens):
        '''check the alien touch the edge of screen'''
        for alien in aliens.sprites():
            if alien.x > self.setting.w or alien.x < 0:
            self.change_alien_direction(aliens)
            break

    def change_alien_direction(self,aliens):
        '''if touch the screen move down and change the direction'''
        for alien in aliens.sprites():
            alien.rect.y +=50
            alien.direction *= -1

    def update_alien(self,alien,aliens):
        self.check_alien_edge(aliens)
        aliens.update()

    def blit_alien(self,alien,aliens):
        aliens.draw(self.setting.screen)

    def ckeck_ship_collide(self,ship,alien,state,aliens):
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(ship,aliens):
        state.ship_left -= 1
        if state.ship_left >= 0:
            aliens.empty()
            alien.create(self.setting,aliens)
            state.ship_left -= 1

            ship.rect.center = ship.screen_rect.center
            ship.rect.bottom = ship.screen_rect.bottom

            ship.x = float(ship.rect.centerx)
            ship.y = float(ship.rect.centery)

            sleep(0.5)
        else:
            print("Gamer over")

    def blit_screen(self,ship,alien,sb,bullets,aliens):
        self.setting.screen.fill((255,255,255))
        self.setting.screen.blit(ship.ship,ship.rect)
        self.setting.screen.blit(sb.score,sb.rect)
        self.event(bullets,ship)
        self.blit_alien(alien,aliens)


def game():
    pygame.init()
    setting=Setting(1200,800)
    screen=setting.screen 
    state=Game_state(setting)
    sb=Scoreboard(setting,state)
    ship=Ship(screen,setting)
    function=Function(setting)
    bullet=Bullet(setting,ship)
    bullets=pygame.sprite.Group()
    alien=Alien()
    aliens=pygame.sprite.Group()
    alien.create(setting,aliens)                  

    while True:
        function.blit_screen(ship,alien,sb,bullets,aliens)
        function.move(ship)
        function.update_alien(alien,aliens)
        function.blit_bullet(alien,state,sb,bullets,aliens)
        function.ckeck_ship_collide(ship,alien,state,aliens)
        pygame.display.flip()
game()
```